# Can't get a placeholder to appear in an input box

Tags: html

```css
.main {
  background-color: #151515;
}

.signup_container {
  align-items: center;
  justify-self: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #151515;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  padding: 0 50px;
}

.signup_content {
  padding-top: 100px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background-color: #ff8177;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ff0844 0%, #ffb199 100%);
  background-size: 50%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
}

.signup_input-position {
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-self: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="signup_container">
    <div class="signup_content">
      <h1>Sign Up</h1>
      <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Username" class="signup_input-position" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a class and a place holder there however I don't understand why the placeholder isn't appearing in the input box.

[Image of the signup page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9063L.png)

Some of the css defined in the html

Comment: I put your code in a snipper in your question and it works fine. Please edit it so we have a [mcve] to work with. There's probably CSS and possibly JavaScript that's you're missing

Comment: One sec I can get my css.

Comment: Why are you setting the `*-text-fill-color` to `transparent`? That seems to be the cause. This property is non-standard anyway and should not be used

Comment: If I do that the big sign up text gets made black but it does fix it one sec

Comment: https://imgur.com/8HIwYj8

Comment: So just set the color of the H1 with `color: something`

Comment: If I do that I completely remove the gradient that it is meant to create

Answer (score 0):

you use

```
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
-moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

that means input color will be transparent, that's why the placeholder was not visible. You can use another color instead of using transparent.

```css
.main {
  background-color: #151515;
}
h1 {
  color: white;
}
.signup_container {
  align-items: center;
  justify-self: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
  background-color: #151515;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  padding: 0 50px;
}

.signup_content {
  padding-top: 100px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background-color: #ff8177;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ff0844 0%, #ffb199 100%);
  background-size: 50%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  text-align: center;
}

.signup_input-position {
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-self: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="signup_container">
    <div class="signup_content">
      <h1>Sign Up</h1>
      <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Username" class="signup_input-position" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yer ik but it removes the gradient it was meant to create:
imgur.com/8HIwYj8

Comment: I don't understand what you have told, have you got your answer?

Comment: Nah, if you run the code snippet you can see how the big "Sign Up" test is black, it is meant to have a graident which appears in my code snippet where the placeholder is invisible

Comment: @Neptuwune can you please check my snippet, I edited my answer. is it ok for you?

Comment: Nah you don't get it, there is meant to be a colour gradient

Comment: yeah, I really don't get you. where you want gradient color. Can you just tell me?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it, I will just go with a simple color instead of a gradient. Can't be asked to waste my time with it.